# How can I categorize a collection of selected places on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

On Google Maps I can save and/or label a specific place. When I do that for many specific places I would like to categorize them, so that I can show the places of a specific category, both as a list and as shown on the maps.

For example, can I categorize the places by restaurants, grocery stores, laundromats, libraries, parks, so that I can show the places belonging to the category of grocery stores on the maps and/or as a list?

I don't find that labeling each place with some category allows me to select places of a category, or am I missing something?

Note that I am not talking about the default categorization of places on Google Maps but about self-categorization of self-selected places using Google Maps.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to create a custom map and have the ability to categorize a set of locations to show each category selectively.

While building [a custom map to show AWS, Azure & Google Cloud datacenters](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1Ya9vEAMJuJYNJ6m9XUurQdu_qEsG-bJ4&ll=39.977913374763915%2C-92.8125&z=4), I found the following articles useful -

- [Make A Google Map With Layers You Can Turn On & Off](http://www.gatehousenewsroom.com/2016/05/09/make-a-google-map-with-layers-you-can-turn-on-and-off/) (original
  article isn't available so the link to cached copy)
- [Plotting data on    a Google Map directly from Google Sheets](http://www.webchick.net/node/132)